# 2.4.6: Filter available attribute sets according to product type, using a plugin

Tags: plugin, attribute-set, option, request, dropdown-options

In my custom plugin, the InstallData.php script creates a custom attribute set. For the purposes of this Q&A, we will call it 'Custom Attribute Set #1'.

I would like the attribute set to only be applicable to products of type 'simple'.

In order to achieve this, I have implemented the following plugin:

```
<?php
namespace MyOrganisation\MyModule\Plugin;

use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\AttributeSet\Options as AttributeSetOptions;
use Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface;

class AttributeSetOptionsPlugin
{
    /**
     * @var RequestInterface $request
     */
    private RequestInterface $request;

    public function __construct(
        RequestInterface $request
    ) {
        $this->request = $request;
    }

    public function afterToOptionArray(
        AttributeSetOptions $subject,
        $result
    ) {

        // If the user is attempting to create a new product
        if($this->request->getActionName() === 'new') {

            // If the product type is not 'simple'.
            if($this->request->getParam('type') !== 'simple') {

                $result = array_filter($result, function($attributeSet) {

                    // Exclude all attribute sets with the label 'Custom Attribute Set #1'.
                    // TODO: Later we should compare against a centralised list of attribute set labels, to ensure coherence across the application as well as offer greater extensibility.
                    if($attributeSet['label'] === 'Custom Attribute Set #1') {
                        return false;
                    }

                    return true;

                });
            }
        }

        return $result;
    }
}
```

If I inject the logger and test the returned value of `$result`, it is correct - where the product type does not equal 'simple', the custom attribute set is removed from the `$result` array.

However, the change is not reflected in the admin panel and, when I attempt to create a new product of any type, 'Custom Attribute Set #1' remains visible in the dropdown list.

Not sure if I should be creating a custom view in order to consume an alternative data source, or if the plugin should be triggered in a different location (earlier, perhaps), or something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Attribute Set list on the admin product page is loaded using the Attribute Set Collection. Take a look at the following method to see how Magento retrieves the options :
`\Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\AttributeSet::getOptions`.

This class is called in the file `vendor/magento/module-catalog/etc/adminhtml/di.xml`, and is one of the many modifiers used to generate the product form and its data :

```xml
<item name="attribute_set_id" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="class" xsi:type="string">Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\AttributeSet</item>
    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">20</item>
</item>
```

You will have to filter this list too.

To do so, you can add your own modifier, specify a `sortOrder` value to be executed after Magento creates the `attribute_set_id` field, and use it to edit the dropdown options.

In your your module, create the following file :

**app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/adminhtml/di.xml** :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <virtualType name="Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\Pool">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="modifiers" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="attribute_set_id_filter" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="class" xsi:type="string">Vendor\Module\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\AttributeSetFilter</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">21</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>
</config>
```

Then you will have to create the class, in which you will be able to retrieve the attribute set list, and filter it.

**app/code/Vendor/Module/Ui/DataProvider/Product/Form/Modifier/AttributeSetFilter** :

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Vendor\Module\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier;

use Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\AbstractModifier;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Locator\LocatorInterface;


/**
 * Filter options of the "Attribute Set" field
 */
class AttributeSetFilter extends AbstractModifier
{
    /**
     * @var LocatorInterface
     */
    protected $locator;

    /**
     * @param LocatorInterface $locator
     */
    public function __construct(
        LocatorInterface $locator
    ) {
        $this->locator = $locator;
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function modifyMeta(array $meta)
    {
        if ($name = $this->getGeneralPanelName($meta)) {
            if ($this->locator->getProduct()->getTypeId() == \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Type::TYPE_SIMPLE) {
                $options = &$meta[$name]['children']['attribute_set_id']['arguments']['data']['config']['options'];
                // Add your filtering logic on the $options variable here
                // The actual 'attribute_set_id's options' element of the $meta array will be modified because $options variable is a pointer to it
            }
        }

        return $meta;
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function modifyData(array $data)
    {
        return $data;
    }
}
```

Edit this code to apply your filtering logic on the `$options` variable.

*Note : As the `$options` variable is a pointer to the `options` key inside the $meta varaible, you won't need to reaffect it to the $meta variable.*

---

Another solution would be to create an after plugin on the `\Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\AttributeSet::getOptions` method, but I would avoid creating too much plugin when there are other clean ways to do it.